# How can I establish communication between a Raspberry Pi and a Nayax VPOS system using Multi-drop bus (MDB) protocol over USB?

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb

I have been trying to find a way to get a Raspberry Pi to communicate with a Nayax VPOS system and have been told that this would require an MDB to USB interface. Is this true and if so, what would be required on the software front to make the communication work?

I have been looking into MDB protocol and have some knowledge but I am not sure how to implement this on Raspberry Pi, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The manual says there are a few RS232 pins on the 40-pin interface. Have you tried connecting to them directly and see if you can read them? https://www.livewellvending.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/VPOS-Touch-User-Manual.pdf

Comment: Alternatively, maybe something like this which you may already have found? https://pinout.xyz/pinout/mdb2pi_hat